# One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: Property name 'Transport Method' is already defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just run one of my pages and i get this error as you see in screenshots and here :

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Transport Method: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Transport Method' is already defined.
```

i dont have any idea what it means and i also searched for this error , but not to much info showing up and i dont have any 'Transport Method' property in my Contact Class.Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx
[image]

Comment: It could be a property on a navigation property, too.  So you have to check your entire model for a duplicate property of that name.  It could be defined via Data Annotations/Fluent API.

Comment: @DanielLorenz I just checked every where in Contact Class and there is no property with this name "Transport Method" ,and the error make me confused ... idont should check the 15 class's i have or just that class marked in error

Comment: The first creation of the dbcontext will validate the entire model, so ANY entity could be causing this issue.